# use lastChild selector with style attribute in react

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors

Is it possible to select `last-child` using `style` in react ? Something like:

```js
{
  _.range(12).map((i)=>(
    <div
      style={{
          borderBottom: 'solid 3px',
          '&last-child': {
            borderBottom: 'solid 1px',
          }
      }}
  >
    row n*{i}
  </div>
}
```

We can handle this case with:

```js
borderBottom: `solid ${ (i !== 11) ? 3 : 1 }px`
```

but I wonder if it's possible using `&last-child`. I would like to be able to select any [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes), such as `hover`

Comment: Why not `index === array.length`?

Comment: I would like to select any *pseudo class*

Comment: If you have css other than inline-style, you can use [`.parent > div:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Comment: You're already computing an inline style. You don't need selectors. Just compute the style.

Comment: Let's say I want to use `:hover`, is there a way to do so with inline ?

Comment: No. Inline styles are for attaching CSS rules (not selectors) directly to an element. In general you should use a stylesheet where possible and resort to inline styles only when you need specific/computed exceptions. You _could_ put an onHover in there and update state and re-render with new styles, but why do all that when you can have a simple, static css rule?